# Using ffmpeg to export frames in a single row tile

Tags: ffmpeg

Exporting all the frames in a *single* Nx1 tile can be done like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "fps=5,tile=100x1" output.jpg
```

The problem is that I don't know up front how many frames are there going to be, so I specify a much higher number than expected (based on the movie length and fps). Ideally I would like something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "fps=5,tile=Nx1" output.jpg
```

Where `Nx1` would tell `ffmpeg` to create an image as wide as the number of exported frames.

I know there is a `showinfo` filter that might come as handy, but I was never able to integrate it so that it's output is used as input for `tile`.

Also, I tried pre-calculating the number of frames based on the movie `duration` and `fps` but this was never very accurate. Even for exactly 3.000s movie and 3fps it was producing 8 frames.

Comment: Where did you check that it was producing 8 frames for 3s @ 3fps?

Comment: @aergistal I just exported the video with tile=10x1 and saw that there are 8 regular frames and 2 black frames, but those black frames are not part of the video itself. Also when I used -loglevel verbose, it was printing "8 frames out".

Comment: If the last frame is missing you can try `fps=fps=[f]:eof_action=pass`. Video not starting at PTS 0 might also pose problems. If you can do it in two steps you can just output individual images and stitch them with ImageMagick using `convert +append` or `montage`.

Comment: For some of the slightly longer videos (1min for example), more frames were missing (~1-6). I ended up doing it in 2 steps with the help from ImageMagick.